# MySQL - make ORDER BY sort by number embedded into a string field

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing

My data (when ordered using ORDER BY) looks like so:

```
PART-320
PARTe-160 reducer
PARTe-240
PART-90
PART-30
PARTe-160
PART-960
PART-other
PARTe-250
PART-???
PARTe-1400
PARTe-1000
PARTe-30
...
PART-40
PARTe-120
PARTe-10
PART-120
PARTe-350
```

I'd like to sort it using some rules kind of like so:

- numerical part is sorted by first
- the rest kind of doesn't matter

I am thinking of parsing out the part after `-` (hyphen) but not sure what to do about the line with "reducer", nor how to handle question marks `???` in one of the lines or `other`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `substring_index()`, assume the numeric part is comes after the `-`:

```
order by substring_index(col, '-', -1) + 0
```

The `+ 0` does a "silent conversion" of the last field.

Comment: that is pretty ingenious I must say  -- `substring_index` with `-1` with `+0` which also implicitly casts to a number